# Where is the best place to open and close a database when it is used across many activities and/or fragments in an app?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm writing writing an app and every activity and service uses my Sqlite database. As it stands I instantiate the db (with db = new DBAdapter(this);) and open it in the onCreate method of all activities and close it in the onStop method. Is this the right way to go about it or should I somehow make the db global? Or should it be passed between activities somehow in a bundle?

I'm also looking to change my UI to use fragments and that will mean even more components that access the same db. It seems relatively okay to open and close the db in each activity when there are no fragments because progression through them is linear. But with fragments (which I'm just starting to learn about) there can be many of them on the same screen so if they each had their own instance of the database I'd be worried about them conflicting. So I'd appreciate any advice on how a db should be handled in these situations.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not write a class that is external to all of the activities that handles all of the database transfers? That way you query the class which handles all of the db access.

You can put a layer of abstraction between your application and your database, that way all your application needs is a function call (or calls) with the right arguments.

That way of all the db access in your application if you decide you want to tinker you only have to change one set of code, the function calls will likely remain largely the same.

As far as efficiency is concerned, as long as you aren't pulling **tons** of data from storage, it likely won't matter how you leave the database open.

But for the sake of it, it might be worth it to open and close for each query, what if their battery dies while the db is open?

Either way, with a level of abstraction between the database and your application, you can change how the database is accessed easily.

Comment: Brilliant idea, thank you :-) I don't know why I didn't think of it myself. The ActiveAndroid library mentioned in the first answer basically appears - from its website - to do the same thing but at the same time encapsulating queries into class objects and properties. It looks really cool. But for me, and just for now, I'm happy to make my own class - should be great fun... I love working with databases in android.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using framework instead of coding the database access code, then, please look at Active Android (http://www.activeandroid.com/).  In our application, we are now freed from worrying about when to  open and close database as this framework takes care of doing that.

It uses a Application object's onCreate and onTerminate to initialize and uninitialize the framework, during which it performs operations related to opening and closing database.  You can take cue from that and follow similar model if you, for some reason, don't want to use the framework

Comment: Thank you :-) That looks wonderful. It looks a bit complicated for me setting it up - because I'm not familiar with adding external libraries and plugins etc in Eclipse - but I'll definitely 'take cue from that' to create my own similar class. But I'll still read more about this Active Android library because it really does look cool and definitely something I'd want to use in the future. Cheers :-)

Comment: Yeah sure. We like it at our office, and are moving all our hand-written database access code to this framework.